# Merging rows in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose I have a table with 4 columns: ID (auto-increment), name, phone and e-mail. The problem is that sometimes the name is repeated. For example:

```
+----+------+-------+--------------+
| id | name | phone | email        |
+----+------+-------+--------------+
|  1 | aaa  |       |              |
|  2 | aaa  | 123   |              |
|  3 | aaa  |       | aaa@test.com |
+----+------+-------+--------------+
```

Which would be the best way to merge these 3 entries into one with all the fields present? The expected result would be:

```
+----+------+-------+--------------+
| id | name | phone | email        |
+----+------+-------+--------------+
|  4 | aaa  | 123   | aaa@test.com |
+----+------+-------+--------------+
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using aggregation, except for the setting of the `id`.  Does this do what you want?

```
select max(id) + 1, name, max(phone) as phone, max(email) as email
from table t
group by name;
```

EDIT:

If you wanted to *insert* a new value and then delete the old ones, you could do:

```
insert into table(name, phone, email)
    select max(id) + 1, name, max(phone) as phone, max(email) as email
    from table t
    group by name
    having count(*) > 1;
```

And then:

```
delete t from table t join
              (select t.name, max(id) as maxid
               from table t
               group by t.name
              ) tt
              on t.name = tt.name and t.id < tt.maxid;
```

Comment: Assuming that the id field is the PK to this table, since you don't know what ids are already present I don't think you want to be selecting an id field. In his example above, if you already had a row with id 4 corresponding to the name bbb, then your statement would fail. If there's no PK then it wouldn't cause an error, although given that the id field is an auto-inc you probably wouldn't want to specify it anyway

Comment: The first bit is just what I needed. I don't need to insert, just select combining all the rows. Thank you!!

Comment: In that case disregard what I said!

Comment: However, what @Vyas says is true, so you might wanna remove the second part of the answer. Cheers!